# Dynamic array of struct with string members

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic, struct

I've created in my program a dynamic array of struct which members are also strings. I've some doubts about safe behaviour in manipulating strings inside the dynamically allocated struct.
Am I allowed to update or concatenate strings as I do with normal string variables?
Do I have to concern about the boundaries of the allocated memory of the struct?

To make it a bit clear, I've something like the following **pseudocode**:

First I've the struct declaration

```
struct myStruct
{
    ...
    int data1;
    int data2;
    std::string myString1;
    std::string myString2;
    ...
}
```

Then the struct is allocated

```
mystruct testStruct*;
testStruct = new mystruct [MAX_DEPTH];
```

The strings are initialized

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX_DEPTH; i++)
{
    ...
    testStruct[i].myString1 = "";
    testStruct[i].myString2 = "";
    ...
}
```

During the program cycles, the strings values are assigned and updated

```
...
testStruct[N].myString1 = "Some text";
...
testStruct[N].myString1 += "Some other text";
...
```

Here I'm not sure to deal correctly with the allocated memory.

Are these assignments correct, and safe, even inside a dynamically allocated array of struct?
I'm risking to break the boundary of dynamic allocated memory for myStruct variable?

Thanks

EDIT:
I've corrected the [i] wrongly placed in the psuedocode.

Comment: I think you mean testStruct[i].myString1 = "Some text";  Also you don't need to initialise the strings first.  Also use std::vector to hold your structs.

Comment: Yes, it is completely safe. But in *modern C++* you be using `std::vector` rather than allocating the array manually.

Comment: @quamrana, thanks. I've corrected them

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Thanks both for the answer and for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the expressions within the loop are incorrect

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX_DEPTH; i++)
{
    ...
    testStruct.myString1[i] = "";
    testStruct.myString2[i] = "";
    ...
}
```

You mean

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX_DEPTH; i++)
{
    ...
    testStruct[i].myString1 = "";
    testStruct[i].myString2 = "";
    ...
}
```

But in any case the loop is redundant because the objects of the type std::string were already default initialized when the memory for the array of structures were allocated.

As for these statements

```
testStruct.myString1[N] = "Some text";
...
testStruct.myString1[N] += "Some other text";
```

then again you need to apply the subscript operator to the pointer `testStruct`. For example

```
testStruct[N].myString1 = "Some text";
...
testStruct[N].myString1 += "Some other text";
```

> I'm risking to break the boundary of dynamic allocated memory for
>   myStruct variable?

If you will use an index that is greater than or equal to `MAX_DEPTH` with the pointer `testStruct` then it is evident that there will be undefined behavior,

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors in the pesudo code, I've corrected them in the questiong. I'm not worried about index greater or equal to MAX_DEPTH, I was unsure about the dynamic allocation of strings inside a dynamically allocate struct.

Answer (score -1):

class string is implemented in the following manner:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename charT,
              typename traits = char_traits<charT>,
              typename Allocator = allocator<charT>>
            class basic_string;

    typedef basic_string<char> string;
}
```

The third argument is the memory model used by the string class which handles the allocation and deallocation of memory.